# Create date with custom format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to be able to create a date in this format:

```
2015-05-07T13:28:01+0300
        //^           ^ Here it is different from ISO 8601, which has a colon there
        //| Don't know how to get this 'T' into my current format
```

Note that it is not exactly the same as: `ISO 8601 date`.

Right now I'm only able to create dates in this format:

```
2015-05-07 13:28:01+0300
```

For this I use the pattern:

```
Y-m-d H:i:sO
```

But how can I get the `T` into the date format?

Comment: Have you tried `Y-m-dT H:i:sO`?

Comment: This is `ISO 8601 date` format

Comment: @Hexaholic Yes, I tried. This is the result: '2015-05-07CEST12:50:31+0200'

Comment: @Rizier123 It is close, but time zone is in different way. I need exactly +0000 format, but ISO 8601 date format is +00:00. How could I achieve such a result? Ref:http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @eatmypants Show from where you get your date in which format and in which exact format you want to change it. Or do you just want to create a date in this format?

Comment: @Rizier123 I get it DateTime(void) constructor. To which format I want to change it - in topic header.